# MariaDB doesn´t start

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Mysql (MariaDB) doesn´t start. Error Log:

```
140426 19:29:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp'
```

On the internet i could not find anything about this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in your `my.cnf`, most likely in section `[mysqld]`, option: `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`.
Try commenting it out.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you partially upgraded `mysql server`, e.g. only `mysql-common` package if that's `debian` you're talking about. And the solution is to upgrade the other packages as well, supposedly like this:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```